# Debugger is not starting, exit code 0

Tags: .net-core, rider

I have Problems getting the debugger up in JetBrains Rider IDE. I have created a clean and empty `.net core` Terminal application.

[image]

If i start the Debugger no code seems to be executed, the breakpoint is not hit. And the Debug Console window shows:

```
"..\JetBrains Rider 2018.2.3\lib\ReSharperHost\JetBrains.Debugger.Worker.exe" 
   --mode=client --frontend-port=54227

Process finished with exit code 0.
```

No errors or popups indicate what is wrong.  The debugger works as expected if I create a empty .NET Framework Console application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it was .Net Core SDK version or 32/64 bit matching issue. I had 64bit Rider 2018.2.3, and 32bit .Net Core SDK v2.1.403. Uninstalling all the .Net SDKs and installing 64bit SDK v2.1.500 resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Similarly I had the same problem when JetBrains Rider wouldn't debug C# code.